# How to stop iCloud syncing and backup when user is on 3G

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, icloud

I am new to iCloud and I wanted to ask if there is a way to stop iCloud syncing if the user is connected to the internet using his mobile data panning

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reachability to detect if Wifi is available ( and if user is using Mobile Data ), then manually stop/resume syncing depending on your settings ( eg. start when user WIFI is available and stop after it becomes unavailable ).

if you are using AFNetworking ( Alamofire on Swift ) have a look at https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#network-reachability-manager

if you are not using AFNetworking , then have a look at Apples sample code how to use reachability  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html